# EditText for numbers with decimal places and suffix

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to create and `EditText` with following features:

1. It should accept only integers and float numbers with certain decimal points. (Let's say two decimal points like `23.45`).
2. When a user enters a number, a `TextWatcher` should immediately put a certain character or string at the end of the text (as a suffix) separated by a blank space (For example, `23.46 $`).
3. User can NOT delete the suffix. Even if he tries, the cursor should go to the end of number. ("End of number" means before the suffix and the space between numbers and suffix. For example, when I try to delete `$` from `23.46 $|`, it should be like `23.46| $`, where `|` is cursor and nothing should be deleted).
4. Dot (or comma) can be deleted.
5. [Optional] Numbers should be grouped when length is more. (Like `12 232 546.45 $`. Three numbers together).
6. No leading dot or more than one zeros

How can I do this?

It would be very helpful for one who wants to use an `EditText` like this since it is very common.

You can see more clear image below.

[image: EditText]
What I tried is below but it is for only integer:

```
public class AmountTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String TAG = "VisaAmountTextWatcher";
private static final String USD_MARK = " $";
private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;
private DecimalFormat dfnd;

private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private int minAmount;
private int maxAmount;
private double currencyRate;

public VisaAmountTextWatcher(EditText editText, TextView textView, int minAmount, int maxAmount, double currencyRate){

    DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("ru"));

    otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###", otherSymbols);
    decimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###", otherSymbols);

    this.editText = editText;
    this.textView = textView;
    this.minAmount = minAmount;
    this.maxAmount = maxAmount;
    this.currencyRate = currencyRate;
}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    String changedString = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

    try {
        String error = "";

        //s is with blank space(s)
        String summaWithoutSpace = s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        if (textView != null) {
            String value = changedString.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            int summaInCents = value.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(value);
            double summaInUsd = FormatUtils.cent2usd(summaInCents);

            if (summaInUsd < minAmount) {
                error = String.format("%s: %d %s", editText.getContext().getString(R.string.min_amount_limit), minAmount, editText.getContext().getString(R.string.usd));
            } else if (summaInUsd > maxAmount) {
                error = String.format("%s: %s %s", editText.getContext().getString(R.string.max_amount_limit), FormatUtils.getFormatSum("" + maxAmount), editText.getContext().getString(R.string.usd));
            }

            textView.setText(ViewUtils.group(summaInUsd * currencyRate));
        }

        int newCursorPos;

        if(summaWithoutSpace.isEmpty()){
            editText.setText("");
            newCursorPos = 0;
        }
        else {
            Number actualNumber = decimalFormat.parse(summaWithoutSpace);
            String formattedString = dfnd.format(actualNumber) + USD_MARK;
            editText.setText(formattedString);
            newCursorPos = formattedString.length() - USD_MARK.length();
        }

        editText.setSelection(newCursorPos);

        if (!error.equals("")) {
            editText.setError(error);
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
        // do nothing?
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);

    }
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your efforts.

Comment: @VicJordan sure!

Comment: @VicJordan I added what I did so far, can you take a look, please